# how to extract a required list of strings from a different string, using lambdas in python

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

```
S = [u'BIGSQL_WORKER', u'DATANODE', u'FLUME_HANDLER', u'HBASE_CLIENT', u'HBASE_REGIONSERVER', u'HCAT', u'HDFS_CLIENT', u'HIVE_CLIENT', u'MAPREDUCE2_CLIENT', u'NODEMANAGER', u'OOZIE_CLIENT', u'PIG', u'SLIDER', u'SOLR', u'SPARK_CLIENT', u'SQOOP', u'YARN_CLIENT', u'ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT', u'ZOOKEEPER_SERVER']
```

I want to remove the strings which have 'CLIENT' in them,

```
F = map(lambda x: x if 'CLIENT' not in x else None, S)
F = [u'BIGSQL_WORKER', u'DATANODE', u'FLUME_HANDLER', None, u'HBASE_REGIONSERVER', u'HCAT', None, None, None, u'NODEMANAGER', None, u'PIG', u'SLIDER', u'SOLR', None, u'SQOOP', None, None, u'ZOOKEEPER_SERVER']
```

I tried pass but did not work inside lambda, any idea ?

Comment: Do you need to use lambdas? Why?

Answer (score 3):

try [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html), which is very versatile and can be used for these things:

```
[s for s in S if 'CLIENT' not in s]
```

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension is probably what you are looking for but you can also use `filter`[<sup>[docs]</sup>](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) rather than map:

```
In [77]: filter(lambda s: 'CLIENT' not in s, S)
Out[77]:
[u'BIGSQL_WORKER',
 u'DATANODE',
 u'FLUME_HANDLER',
 u'HBASE_REGIONSERVER',
 u'HCAT',
 u'NODEMANAGER',
 u'PIG',
 u'SLIDER',
 u'SOLR',
 u'SQOOP',
 u'ZOOKEEPER_SERVER']
```